# no crank for my 2006 chevy malibu

Tags: no-crank-no-start

I have a 2006 cheverlot malibu 4 door sadan that will not start. all the dash lights come afer putting the keey in the ignition the relay is kicking on but it will not start what could it be?

Comment: Have you had the battery tested?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "no-crank", do you mean you turn the key and nothing happens? Or do you turn the key, the motor makes trying to start noises, but never starts?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 " the ignition the relay is kicking on but it will not start"

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar post for a 2009 Malibu ... maybe some of the troubleshooting steps can help you narrow down your issue. Good luck and if there are any other specifics you can share one reviewing this article it may help us help you. Thanks!
['09 Chevy Malibu - No Crank, No Start - Heavy Troubleshooting Already Completed](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/09-chevy-malibu-no-crank-no-start-heavy-troubleshooting-already-completed)